# jQuery <nobr> Selector

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Morning All,

Previously I have been using

```
$("#WebPartWPQ2 .ms-formtable tr:contains('lblName')> td").toggleClass('changedetails');
```

to customise a sharepoint list form, this has worked fine, (I have looked into alternative solutions to improve performance before but seem to achieve similar results)

Is there a selector for `<nobr>` in jquery

I have this working although I need it to match exactly rather than match if "contains".

```
$("#WebPartWPQ2 .ms-formlabel nobr:contains('Change Owner')").toggleClass('changedetails');
```

Thanks in advance
Gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine it with [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to check an exact match, like this:

```
$("#WebPartWPQ2 .ms-formlabel nobr").filter(function() {
  return $.text([this]) === "Change Owner";
}).toggleClass('changedetails');
```

The `$.text()` call is calling `jQuery.text` directly (calling Sizzle really), rather than making a new jQuery object for each `<nobr>` we're checking.

Comment: Hi Nick,I'm afraid this does not seem to work, there are no errors indicated in the JavaScript console, so it appears to just be missing the cells. Any ideas? Many Thanks

Comment: @NickCraver if there is a **span** element in the **nobr** tag, like **<nobr>Comments:<span>*/span></nobr>** , how can I get the nobr and change its text?